# BxSlider change slide to a specific slide on navigation link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I want my BxSlider slide to change to a specific slide when I click on a navigation menu item. If the navigation item is second from the list, I want BxSlider to show the second slide.

My navigation structure is:

```
<html>
<ul id="pagination" class="clearfix">
 <li><a href="#">Voter Tools</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Candidate Tools</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Ballot Issues</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Data &amp; Resources</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Poll Workers</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Press &amp; Public</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul><!-- /#pagination -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've attempted to set up anchors for the clicks. I'd advise looking into the "pagerCustom" parameter of bxSlider: http://bxslider.com/options#pagerCustom

Your anchors will additionally need a data-slide-index in order to function appropriately:

```
<ul id="pagination" class="clearfix">
 <li><a data-slide-index="0" href="#">Voter Tools</a></li>
 <li><a data-slide-index="1" href="#">Candidate Tools</a></li>
 <li><a data-slide-index="2" href="#">Ballot Issues</a></li>
 <li><a data-slide-index="3" href="#">Data &amp; Resources</a></li>
 <li><a data-slide-index="4" href="#">Poll Workers</a></li>
 <li><a data-slide-index="5" href="#">Press &amp; Public</a></li>
 <li><a data-slide-index="6" href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul><!-- /#pagination -->
```

I'm assuming that you have provided the code for your click-able elements, and the actual list items in the slideshow are elsewhere. Something along the lines of:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/Voter_Tools.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/Candidate_Tools.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/Ballot_Issues.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/Data_and_Resources.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/Poll_Workers.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/Press_and_Public.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/Links.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

You should be able to pass the selector for your thumbnail/anchor container ("#pagination") to the pagerCustom parameter of bxSlider. The library handles the rest!

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '#pagination'
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drjeg422/2/
(Please note: the images don't exist)